# DENO mongo atlas connection issue when primary cluster is changing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, deno

As written in deno.land/x/mongo, to connect to mongo Atlas, such configuration should be use :

```
import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.21.0/mod.ts";
    
    const client1 = new MongoClient();
    
    await client.connect({
    db: "<db>",
    tls: true,
    servers: [
      { 
        host: "<host>",
        port: 27017,
      },
    ],
    credential: {
      username: "<user>",
      password: "<password>",
      db: "<db>",
      mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1",
    },
  });
    
 const db = client1.database("TestingDB");
    
 export default db;
```

There, `<host>`should be replaced by a specific cluster address (looks something like that : `cluster0.hmdnu.mongodb.net`) and not a full string as `mongodb+srv://user1:MYPASSWORD@cluster0.hmdnu.mongodb.net/TestingDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority`.

This solution works well. But there is, I believe, a downside : Sometimes, a Mongo cluster can fail and a Secondary cluster can become Primary. Has we are using a specific cluster on our code, that cluster might be down and our program as well. Any one encounter a similar issue ? and how did you resolve it ?

Comment: Alas, not working for me. I just get a Error: MongoError: "Connection failed: failed to lookup address information: No address associated with hostname
But there is nothing wrong using Compass

Comment: Managed to get a connection with the Primary Shard address, like
cluster0-shard-00-01.abc39.mongodb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more cluster

```
 servers: [
  { 
    host: "<host>", /*primary*/
    port: 27017,
  },
  { 
    host: "<host>", /*secondary*/
    port: 27017,
  },
  { 
    host: "<host>", /*secondary*/
    port: 27017,
  },
],
```